# Handle error 422 using restangular

Tags: angularjs, http-status-codes, restangular

I am using restangular(customPut) to make call to a service to update 'password'.  The service when called throws error 422. Neither error handler nor interceptor is able to catch the response. I searched over the net for the possibilities but no luck. Please find my snippet below:

```
app.controller 'PasswordChangeController', ($scope, Flash, Restangular) ->
$scope.changePassword = (user) ->
    Restangular.one('users', 'change-password').customPUT(user).then ((SUCCESS) ->
      $scope.doLogout()
),(response) -> console.log(response)
```

And the http interceptor is as below:

```
app.factory 'authWrapper', ($rootScope, $q, $window, Flash) ->
 request: (config) ->
  config.headers ?= {}
  if $window.localStorage.currentUser?
  user = JSON.parse $window.localStorage.currentUser
  config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer #{user['token']}"
  return config

# Handle response errors like 401 and 403
 responseError: (rejection) ->
  console.log rejection
  switch rejection.status
   when 401
    message = rejection.data.message or 'Your session has expired. Please log in again.'
    if rejection.config.url.search(/sign_in/) isnt -1
      Flash.alert(message).andRefresh()
    else
      Flash.setMsg 'alert', message
      $rootScope.$emit 'auth:unauthorized', (rejection.config.url.search(/sign_out/) isnt -1)
   when 403
    Flash.alert('You are not authorized to perform this action.').andRedirectTo '/'
   when 422
    Flash.alert('Password entered don\'t match with your password')
  $q.reject rejection

app.config ($httpProvider) ->
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push 'authWrapper'
```

Is there any other way to catch error 422?